# Битрикс: фильтровать разделы товаров по бренду если раздел был открыт со страницы бренда

Tags: битрикс, битрикс24

Интернет-магазин на битриксе. Есть страница с брендами. Нажимая на лого бренда открывается страница с товарами этого бренда. Нужно сверху страницы разместить категории (разделы) товаров которые есть у этого бренда. Когда добавляю разделы к бренду, то при нажатии на категорию открываются товары этой категории ВСЕХ брендов. А нужно открывать товары именного того бренда из которого перешли в категорию.

Answer (score 0):

Для вывода товаров нужно использовать catalog.section
у него есть параметр FILTER_NAME например
`'FILTER_NAME'=>'arrFilter',`

тогда для вильтрации у товаров должна быть привязка к брендам по свойству например бренд(код свойства `BRAND`)

тогда фильтр на странице бренда будет выглядеть так

```
global $arrFilter;    
$arrfilter['PROPERTY_BRAND']=$arResult["ID"];
```

Comment: На странице бренда фильтр работает. Но мне нужно чтобы на странице бренда сверху были указаны категории товаров выбирая которые открывались страницы с товаром выбранной категории и именно того бренда из которого сделан выбор.